deduplicating purposefully duplicated layer 2 traffic
Pre-amble: I am wanting to turn n + 1 connections into a single connection where the failover latency is 0 by duplicating traffic over multiple connections and dropping out packets on reception.
Investigation: I have investigated mlvpn which I've discovered simply doesn't do this, besides, I don't want to use non-stock linux components if I can avoid it.
bonding seems to fit the bill, specifically with mode = broadcast which flat out duplicates traffic on all the links.
I have combined this with openvpn tap tunnels which are bonded on either end like so:
                    ----- tap 0 -----
                   /                  \
(home-router) bond0                    bond0 (vps server)
                   \----- tap 1 ------/

There's a bunch of hoops to jump through here, and it's not perfect, but I am able to get this setup working:

I can tcpdump on tap0, tap1 and bond0 and see exactly what I expect to: traffic is duplicated over tap0 and tap1.
I can stop the openvpn process on the server and observe no activity on one of the two taps while seeing a 0 latency failover of ping on bond0

What I cannot do is deduplicate the traffic.
I have looked at nftables, ebtables, and iptables (in descending order of preference). I have also investigated eBPF.
Surely what I'm trying to achieve has been done before, I can't be the first to invent this wheel. Any ideas?

I am wanting to ... by duplicating traffic What I cannot do is deduplicate the traffic ?

This isn't a question, but I'll try to interpret it as such. I am implementing classical active hot-standby: the traffic is being sent in duplicate and at the destination any traffic which made it in duplicate is discarded (i.e. if packet A was sent twice as A1 and A2, the receiving end accepts whichever one came first and discards the second). The sending in duplicate part is solved, the bonding km has a mode specifically designed for this. The reception filtering is the unsolved part.
Yes, they are doing the opposite actions of each other.
